# request.getFile('image') missingMethod in groovy

Tags: groovy

```
def f = request.getFile('image')
```

This call is giving me the following error. although it was working before (i think i switched groovy from 2.1 to 2.3 in eclipse)

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)
```

The call is being made from a mobile phone, by sending a post call with multipart.

From iOS  : 
       MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:path params:parameters httpMethod:method ssl:SSL.boolValue];

```
    if(data1)
        [op addData:data1 forKey:mediaKey1];
    if(data2)
        [op addData:data2 forKey:mediaKey2];
```

Any idea what can this be and how it can be fixed ?

Comment: Take a closer look what is your request type - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest This one does not contain method getFile(String). This method is a part of org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartRequest Could you please show us a little bit more from your implementation so we can see bigger picture? It will be hard to help you without it.

Comment: You say you switched Groovy versions.  Do you really mean that you updated to a new version of Grails?

Comment: Actually its a REST Call form a mobile application, so this is almost all the implementation from the server side. @MattZ no In the project settings i changed groovy